# Ionic 3 tel: button fires twice

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Previously I had the following code for a Call button

```
<a button ion-button outline href="tel:123456789"><ion-icon name="ios-call"></ion-icon></a>
```

It has worked up until RC2, but the button now attempts to call again if I I select cancel.

If I use

```
<a href="tel:123456789><ion-icon name="ios-phone-portrait"></ion-icon></a>
```

or

```
<a ion-button href="tel:123456789"></a>
```

it will still will attempt to call again after the cancel button is selected.

I am unsure of using the CordovaCallNumberPlugin to use the bypassAppChooser as I try to use plugins sparingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Ionic specific to an iOS device. Issue #11510  also issue #11252.

It looks like the ionic team is closing #11252.